# xcode project cannot find header files from framework

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, frameworks

how do you add frameworks in xcode so that a c++ project producing a static cocoa library can find the header files. I have added the opencv2 framework  which is structured as:

```
opencv2.framework

 -Headers
   -imgproc
     -imgproc.hpp

 ...
```

I get build errors that it cannot find

```
  #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

So, I included the path to opencv2.framework in the Header Search Paths but did not work. I also appended the string "opencv2.framework" to the path in Header Search Paths but that did not work either. THe path to Framework search paths is already set in the xcode settings. What else can I do = this is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

please try :

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```